# Why do Kylo Ren's lightsaber and Rey's staff overlap in the official movies poster?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, poster-design

Their weapons overlap as seen below:

[image: official movie poster]

Is there any particular significance to this? It really confused me when I saw it initially, as I assumed she had a red lightsaber.

None of the other movies has this or similar imagery, despite obvious similarities between the films.

Was this intentional by the poster designer? I'm only interested in an official comment by the artist.  It's not Drew Struzon who instead drew this:

[image: Alternate poster]

Comment: Happens in the lego poster too. LOL! https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivn9Txlb7OAhVFkpQKHVh6CtwQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lego.com%2Fen-us%2Fstarwars%2Fgames&psig=AFQjCNFtQ-UGp8XtsbfHY4rK7_rl9ky1vA&ust=1471170111452776

Comment: @kyloren you should know :-P

Comment: The First Order has banned me from answering questions about Star Wars unfortunately.

Comment: Obligatory poster post; http://www.slashfilm.com/orangeblue-contrast-in-movie-posters/

Comment: The "parallels" of their life may be explored in future films or maybe hinting that they duel each other in the end? Or that she is Force Sensitive, too? I mean it was just an artistic/marketing decision, in my opinion.

Comment: The designer of that poster was Bryan Morton; http://makingstarwars.net/2015/10/20321/. I've reached out to him via his blog but he hasn't updated for several months. He has a presence on Instagram but no response page. His listed email address is blocked/non-functional and he doesn't seem to have a twitter account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Aesthetics

While I have no official source for this, I believe the answer is simple.

1. **Poster has lots of characters** - I think it's fair to say that they wanted as many characters as possible all crammed onto the movie poster. Marvel, like Lucasfilm, is owned by Disney, and the same overabundance of characters can be seen in many MCU film posters.
2. **Characters are shown wielding their signature weapons** - Having characters depicted with their corresponding unique/signature weapons both helps audiences associate the characters with their respective weapons as well as makes the overall poster look more exciting, as if they are 'ready for battle'. Han is shown with his signature weapon - his blaster, Rey is shown with her staff, Kylo Ren is shown with his crossguard-lightsaber, etc.

We've established that (1) they probably wanted as many characters as possible on the poster, and that (2) the main characters would be shown holding their weapons, so the inevitable problem the artist is faced with is how to accomplish both without someone's weapons either (a) obstructing our view of another character, or (b) looking awkward or out of place.

Let me explain what I mean. Kylo Ren is holding his lightsaber at an *upward slope*, Finn is holding a blue lightsaber at a *downward slope*, and there is a sort of *horizontal line* at the bottom where all the stormtroopers are standing. Notice how this already seems to form a nice, neat *[triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnJxo.png)*. If Rey were depicted holding her staff, something that easily calls attention to itself due to its size, at a different angle it would break up the flow of the poster making it awkward and possibly even cover up something else on the poster.

**TL;DR:** Aesthetically, if you're going to have that many characters on the poster and have the main ones holding long thin weapons, then some of them are bound to end up lining up like that in order to maintain a smooth viewing experience. It simply made the most sense to have Rey's staff and Kylo Ren's lightsaber line up that way.

[image]

Comment: I cannot unsee that triangle now. +1